# Send email with attachment of excel sheet in wicket

Tags: wicket

I have generated excelsheet using jexcel api on download button but now I want to save it on webapp folder like webapp/excel/report.xls.

so that further i can use it to attach with email.
 Any ideas to achieve this task?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, could you perhaps rephrase it? Sending emails is not wickets responsibility, it should be handled by the service layer.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably save it to a temporary file if you need to save it at all. Google JavaMail to see how to send emails. Sending emails has nothing to do with Wicket btw.